# August 2022 Writing Challenge: Weatherwise

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

As decided by vote, here's the next challenge, proposed by [Mary](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/44281/mary):

> Write a scene in which weather is a significant factor. Whether for effects on the events, or as a thematic comment. Or both.

---

Go onward and write! Then post your story here as an answer, and get feedback in the comments. If you [ask a main site question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) while writing for this challenge, leave a comment below this question or mention it in your answer.

Follow this question if you want to be notified instantly of any new answers.

You can also post and vote on future challenges here: [The next writing challenge could be yours](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2446/34330)

Answer (score 1):

Mist everywhere.  The trees were thick, looming pillars that blurred within strides of him.  The branches were at least high enough to not add to distance, but they formed a canopy that cut off half the already sparse light.  Marcus scowled, pulling his cloak closer against the cold.  He could hardly walk much faster for warmth with this footing, and the mist would only slow him further -- if it did nothing else.

The damp chill brushed against his cheek.  He needed some way to detect magic, and he did not have it.  Here, in this land, he was not weatherwise.  Were mists the natural weather of these mountains?  He took a step forward, on leaves still pliant though bleached pale.  Perhaps it did not matter -- perhaps, even if the mists were magic, it had nothing to do with him.  Who, after all, would wield magic to deal with so unimportant a wanderer as he was?  And he could not go back.

A snarl came out of the trees before him.  He pulled back toward one tree, despite the tangled roots, and peered.  A lupine face, atop a human body, both larger than nature, bear-sized, looked toward him.  Another snarl followed, before his thoughts cohered enough to know -- someone who cared only for him as prey.

Answer (score 1):

"Luna, wake up. My shift's over. Did you forget to hang up the stars again? How are the mortals supposed to enjoy a nice beautiful night if the sky's pitch black?" Solari grumbled, grabbing a handful of stars and quickly placing them along the night sky. There was so much to do before the humans woke up, and his sister was not being much of a help. She kept sleeping even though her shift had already begun.

That was all she ever did. Sleep. How were the other gods going to respect them at this rate? She was the goddess of the Moon, not the goddess of Sleep!

"Can I get a few more minutes? I swear I'll get up eventually..." Luna yawned.

Her brother was not about to let her sleep for another moment. Then, he noticed something beneath Luna's bed of clouds. It was a spear, shaped like a thunderbolt.

Oh no, was that what I think it is? Helios wondered, picking it up and examining it. The first touch sent a painful jolt of electricity down his arm.

"Nice, you found my back scratcher," Luna said, snatching the spear out of Solari's hands and using it to relief an itch. Solari rolled his eyes and stole it back.

"It's not a back scratcher. It's Zephyr's thunderbolt! No wonder the mortals haven't been getting any rain recently. How's he supposed to make any new clouds without this thing?" Solari asked, waiting for Luna to explain herself.

For the first time, his sister awoke, fully alert. "I'm so sorry. It's all my fault...Wait a second, how'd it get here in the first place? Did you invite your boyfriend over while I was asleep?"

Whoops, she caught him there. He brought Zephyr over while she was still having her nap. That must have been how he lost his talisman. They had been...a little distracted.

Solari needed to make this right. He rushed over to the Cloud kingdom, where a handsome god with sleek black hair and striking blue eyes was waiting for him at the top of a giant grey stormcloud.

The poor mortals on the ground below were waiting for an end to this relentless dry spell.

"Whew, that was a long run. Hey, Zephyr. I found something of yours," Solari said, tossing the ancient magic weapon to his boyfriend.

"Oh no, did I leave that at your house again? I'm such a scatterbrain."

"Well, you're a cute scatterbrain, now hurry up and make some storm clouds before the poor mortals die of thirst."

Zephyr struck the cloud below him and the dry spell was ended by a day of gentle rain. Solari wrapped his hand in Zephyr's and the two of them looked to the mortal plane. The mortals seemed grateful, but Zephyr and Solari knew the truth. They messed up big time, and they needed to be a lot more careful in the future.

Comment: I assume that single occurrence of "Helios" should be "Solari"?

Comment: @towr Yes, thank you for telling me. I kept changing the name and must've accidentally defaulted to the old one.

Answer (score 1):

*(This is only the first half of what I intended to write. Hopefully I'll finish it soonish, but the month is almost over so I'm posting this bit, at least.)*

---

Suzette stared out the window at the storm. It was still growing stronger. She smiled. She worried about the damage it might do, but the display of raw power was intoxicating in a way.

She wished she could be more like that storm. She was sure it wouldn't let its classmates bully it. Wouldn't let them call it names. Wouldn't let them laugh at it for oversleeping and missing the first half of a pop quiz. Wouldn't let them get away with making her spells blow up in her face... its face.

Lightning streaked across the sky.

It was strange, though. The weather forecast had been clear skies for the day. The storm had come out of nowhere and caught everyone by surprise. It grew in fits and starts and prompted the teachers to cancel the last few hours of school, so people could get home before it got worse.  This had suited Suzette just fine, because by that point she was about ready to snap.

The walk home had been cold and wet. She hadn't brought her umbrella. And even if she had, the wind would have shredded it. So by the time she got home, she was soaked to the bone. In a way, the physical discomfort had been a welcome distraction.

Once she'd dried off, and changed, unwanted thoughts started intruding again. Thoughts of inadequacy, powerlessness, despair, anger. They drew her to the window, to the storm. She stared at it, only faintly aware of the pull.

Comment: Feel free to update it even after the month is over.